# Invalid literal number by running head command in azure databrick

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I want too run below command in my notebook. My language is Scala 2.11 and my spark version is 2.4.4

```
%fs head mnt/training/UbiqLog4UCI/14_F/log_1-6-2014.txt
```

I have below error:

```
<console>:6: error: Invalid literal number
%fs head /mnt/training/UbiqLog4UCI/14_F/log_1-6-2014.txt
                                   ^
```

**Update for first comment**

I add `"` and i have below error

[image]

Comment: did u try with `%fs head "mnt/training/UbiqLog4UCI/14_F/log_1-6-2014.txt"`

Comment: @Shu please check my update

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in Scala 2.11, underscore is not accepted as a valid literal separator and hence, when it was parsing the path, it found undersore for as a separator and hence the issue. The solution to solve this could be as shown below:

```
val cmd = "%fs head /mnt/training/UbiqLog4UCI/14_F/log_1-6-2014.txt"
import sys.process._
val exitcode = cmd.!
```

Please let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Dose not work. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "%fs": error=2, No such file or directory.

Comment: I missed a '/' in front of "mnt".I have added it.could you check and let me know?

Comment: I have the same error : 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "%fs": error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround

```
val zipsDF = spark.read.json("/mnt/training/UbiqLog4UCI/14_F/log_1-6-2014.txt")
zipsDF.printSchema
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get around with this issue by using dbutils.fs.ls command as below:

**dbutils.fs.head("/mnt/training/UbiqLog4UCI/14_F/log_1-6-2014.txt")**